# Confusion about Graph of $\frac{x}{|x|}$

Tags: functions

$f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}$

How do I know how to plot this graph systematically ?

[image]

I separated the function to $\frac{1}{|x|} (x) $, the function $\frac{1}{|x|}$ looks like a even reciprocal graph but what about the other $x$, how do I plot and get something like the graph shown? I do not see how it links

Comment: what do you mean by systematically?, the function f(x) is just sign(x).

Comment: The function is undefined at $x=0.$ I'm not sure what "systematically" means here, but graphs of discontinuous functions, or functions with isolated undefined values, are not easy to draw. Different techniques are used to indicate  the undefined value. One is to put an open circle at the ends of the two lines, to indicate the function is not defined at the ends.

Comment: @alosc $\operatorname{sign}(x)$ is defined at $x=0,$ so it is only almost the sign function.

Comment: You have a pseudoalgorithm to sketch graph of elementary functions. The definition of $|x|$ is given by collecting the values of the elementary functions $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto -x$ in the cases $x\geq0$ and $x<0$. You can then divide your analysis in those two same cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if $x > 0$, then $|x| = x$ (like $|5|=5$), so $x/|x| = 1$.

Alternatively, if $x < 0$, then $|x| = -x$ (like $|-5| = 5 = -(-5)$), so $x/|x|=-1$.

what happens at $x=0$?

Comment: Of course, you could plot point by point, i.e. finding the values of $f(x)$ for $x=-43, -5, -2, -1, 345, \pi$. This way, you will rapidly understand the 3 cases @gt6989b has used.